# Http patch issue using fiddler

Tags: http, odata, fiddler, patch

```
[HttpPatch]
public HttpResponseMessage UpdateDividendInformation([FromBody]BEDividendInformationRequest bedividendInformationRequest, Delta<BEAccountDividendSetup> beAccountDividendSetup)
```

When I am calling from fiddler using http patch its showing:

> "Can't bind multiple parameters  error" .

Please anyone help in this. I am using Delta class for tracking changed entities. So how to send values through fiddler.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, There is at most `1` parameter allowed from body because the request content maybe read only once.

In your action, you mark the first parameter `[FromBody]`, meantime, `Delta<T>` is decorated with `[NonValidatingParameterBinding]` attribute in OData Web API, That's a parameter from body. So, you have two parameters which will bind from body. Therefore, it's obvious that you got the such error message.

However, the error message should contain the parameter names. Do you omit it?

Comment: Thanks sam,i am passing all parameters from fiddler request body and same time its getting handled using complex type parameter,I will try this out. using nonvalidatingparameterbinding